# Web service with database : SqlException

Tags: sql-server, database, web-services, sqlexception

I wrote a web service which works with SQL Server'08 Database

When I try to invoke a web method, I get this:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user &#39;IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NET v4.0&#39;.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean enlistOK)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, TimeoutTimer timeout)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(SqlConnection owningObject, TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlConnectionManager.UseConnection(IConnectionUser user)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.get_IsSqlCe()
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.InitializeProviderMode()
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute(Expression query)
   at System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at route.Logic..ctor() in C:\Users\Ilya\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MobitourLibrary\route\Logic.cs:line 20
   at Service..ctor() in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\RouteGen\App_Code\Service.cs:line 14
```

Where is the problem?
Other win forms application what uses the same DB works fine, why WS doesn't?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The web service will be operating under a different user account from the WinForms application. The WinForms application will be operating from the user account of the logged in user, while the web service will be the account that ASP.NET uses.

You need to set that account up in SQL Server and give it the relevant permissions.

Basically, you need to add the login to the Server, and add that login as a user to each database that requires it.

Here's the step by step instructions when you are in SQL Server Management Studio:

- In the object explorer, open up your SQL Server tree and go into the Security-->Logins branch
- Right-click "Logins" and select "New Login..."
- Next the login Name, click "Search"
- Click "Advanced" to get the "Select User or Group" dialog
- Click "Find Now"
- Scroll through the list at the bottom of the dialog and find the relevant user and double click it. The dialog will close.
- Press "Okay". The dialog will close.
- Back in the "Login - New" dialog press "OK"

You now have a new Login.

Now, to create the user in the database.

- Open up the Databases branch of your tree.
- Open up the branch for the specific database you need, then it's Security-->Users branch.
- Right click "Users" and select "New User..."
- Write a user name (it does not have to match the login name, but generally it does)
- Next to "Login name" press the "..." button
- Press "Browse" in the Select Login Dialog
- Check the login name you want in "Browse for Objects" dialog.
- Press "OK". The dialog will close
- Press "OK". The Select login dialog will close.
- Select the "Schemas owned by this user" - normally "db_owner"
- Select the Database role membership - normally it will be a specific role that has been created by the DBA, if not then db_datareader & db_datawriter. If you have issues, select db_owner then work with your DBA to correct the permissions afterwards (you do not want to assign the ASP.NET process with DB Owner permissions unless you really must, it is a security breach waiting to happen)
- Press "OK" to close the Database User New dialog.

It should all be good now.

**OR**

You can change the connection string in the web service to get it to connect to SQL Server using a specific account.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I didn't clearly understand what login I need to add to the SQL Server?

Comment: If you read the exception message it tells you: Login failed for user "IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NET v4.0".

Comment: I've updated the answer to give step-by-step instructions which works on my instance of SQL Server 2008 Management Studio

Comment: It's great!However what user name I should add?I have nothing similar to "IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NET v4.0". There is "NETWORK SERVICE", maybe I need this?There is "REMOTE ACCESS" also for example

Comment: The APPPOOL actually logs in as a specific user, you can go to IIS to see what identity is associated with the app pool then set that up with SQL Server. More info here: http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/624/application-pool-identities/

Also it is also possible to set up specific SQL Server login accounts and use those in your connection string as an alternative rather than windows accounts.

Comment: ApplicationPoolIdentity is associated with my app pool (ASP.NET v4.0), but I can't find something similar when I'm creating new login in SQL Server!

Comment: I see what you're saying, you may have to create a separate Windows account for this purpose and add that login to SQL server, and of course add read/write to the DB for that account.  Then change the AppPool to run under that Windows account as well.  Make sure the password is not set to expire for that account so you don't have troubles later, and that it has acccess to any other resources your website needs to run.

Answer (score 2):

`Colin Mackay` has provided detailed answer to your question. Here are my two cents.

If you have Active Directory domain setup in your environment, I would **not** recommend including  `user id` and `password` in your connection. Instead, I would suggest the following:

1. Create a domain account say `MyDomain\webservice`, where **MyDomain** would be active directory domain and **webservice** would be the Windows user account in that domain. In `SQL`, provide this new domain account user with appropriate permissions to access the database.
2. In `Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager`, change the Application Pool to run under this service account. If you are running IIS 7.5, following steps can be performed to do that:
3. In `IIS`, expand your `<server name>` node and click on `Application Pools`.
4. It is better to create a new `Application Pool`, so that you don't disturb the functionality of other applications that might use the application pool `ASP.NET v4.0`.
5. Create the new application pool (say `WebServiceAppPool`) similar to ASP.NET v4.0 application pool, except that the new application pool will use the **Identity** of the newly created domain account `MyDomain\webservice` instead of the usual **ApplicationPoolIdentity**.
6. On the `Advanced Settings` option of the virtual directory/site where your web service is deployed to, change the **Application Pool** property to use the newly created application pool `WebServiceAppPool`.

I believe that this set up is more secure and also it will avoid hard coding user id and passwords in the connection string.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The message clearly says it: **LOGIN FAILED** ..... the user (`IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NET v4.0` trying to connect to the database doesn't have permissions there.

Not knowing any other details, I'm assuming this is a ASP.NET web application / webservice hosted in IIS, and you most likely have a connection string to the database that has the `Integrated Security=SSPI` setting turned on - therefore, the current user (here the IIS apppool user) tries to connect to the database - and can't.

So change your connection string (see lots of samples on http://www.connectionstrings.com) to specify a specific database user that *can* connect:

```
server=YourServer;database=YourDatabase;User ID=SomeValidUser;Pwd=Top$ecret
```

Comment: I have "Integrated Security=True" in my connection string, it is enough to turn it to False?

Comment: Personally, I'm not a fan of connection strings that contain passwords. I'd stick with the integrated security and get it sorted out on the SQL Server side of things, but that's my personal opinion.